# Toastbar message display with empty when clear is called

Tags: codenameone

I'm having issues with Toastbar being called with clear() method actually not taking the toastbar away instead it clears the message and display empty with background shown in the image.

I have tried to setExpires(0) after the time, it still doesn't help.

Second question, if a form has more than one toastbar message to show - both the messages will overlap on each other.

Please advise.

```
ToastBar.Status status = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
status.setMessage("Message");
status.setExpires(4000);
status.show();
new UITimer(() -> {
    status.clear();
}).schedule(4000, false, this);
```

[image]

Comment: I think we might need a new method to remove toastbars this looks like padding. Let me check.

Comment: Sure Shai. Thank You.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me.  It must be interacting with something else in your project.  E.g. Have you defined any custom styles (especially ToastBar or ToastBarMessage)?  Can you post a more complete test case that make this reproducible?

Comment: This happens when we have more than one message to display on the form- Lets say I have to display around 10 error messages in if-else loops based on the conditions. It will clear the message with padding issue or will overlap the messages one on top another. second scenario would this happen when I go back and forth between the forms, if I go to next form before the setexpires() time, and come back to the back the same form will make this happen. Please advise.Thanks